# Where can I find old version of Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I was deleting a couple of cells in my Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio code but the computer crashed at that moment.
When I reboot the PC and open the notebook file, there is only one cell which is empty.

Where can I find previous version of this Jupyter notebook file?

(The OS is Windows 10)